# can not run npx react-native init MyApp in react native CLI

Tags: android, node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm

I try to make a new react native cli app using `npx react-native init Kick`  but after some time this error appear

**Error log**

````
Downloading template
error Error: Command failed: npm install --save --save-exact react-native@latest
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Object Not Found - GET https://skimdb.npmjs.com/registry/remove-trailing-separator/-/remove-trailing-separator-1.1.0.tgz - not_found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'remove-trailing-separator@https://skimdb.npmjs.com/registry/remove-trailing-separator/-/remove-trailing-separator-1.1.0.tgz' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404
pm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-07-16T15_48_17_958Z-debug.log```

OS: Windows 10
SDK: Android
npm: version 7.9.0
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

1. Updating Node.js
2. Run npm cache clean command in Command prompt
   (or)
3. Run  reactive-native init in command prompt as Administrator (on Windows OS)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible as you miss some steps while development setup.
Here's the link through which you can set-up your environment.

[https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup][1]

Just follow the instruction properly, for running the app.